# Crear una cuenta regresiva para mi website en función de plays de SPOTIFY

Tags: java, html

Tenemos una banda de pop/rock que tiene mas de 40 canciones en Spotify. Lo que necesitamos es incorporar a nuestra pagina web oficial de la banda un contador de cuenta regresiva que empiece en 1,750,000 y que cada vez que alguien (cualquier persona del mundo) haga PLAY en alguna cancion nuestra de spotify, el contador de nuestra web automáticamente tenga una valor menos. Es decir, si empieza en 1,750,000 y voy a SPOTIFY y le doy PLAY a una canción, automáticamente el contador muestre 1,749,999. Es para una campaña de marketing. Es posible hacerlo? Gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo mirar [esto](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/) para empezar !

Comment: si @NaCl lo lei pero me parece que no incluye lo que estoy necesitando

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo por qué la etiqueta de [java](/questions/tagged/java), creo que no es correcta. En todo caso, Spotify ofrece una [API para web](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/),y SDK's para [iOS](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/) y para [Android](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/).

> **Resumen Ejecutivo**: no puedes obtener esa información usando la API de Spotify porque no la ofrece. Una alternativa podría ser usar un servicio de redireccionador como bit.ly y [contar los clics](http://dev.bitly.com/link_metrics.html#v3_link_clicks).

En la [Consola del programador](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/), puedes ver la información que proporcionan, por artista, album, track, etc. Cuando hablas de artista puedes ver sus tracks [más populares](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-artist-top-tracks/) pero el índice es un número entre el 0 y el 100, donde 100 es el album más popular, pero solo ofrecen el resultado y no la fórmula.

Cuando pides un track particular, obtienes esta información:

```
[toledano ~/proyectos]$ curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6b2oQwSGFkzsMtQruIWm2p" -H "Accept: application/json"
{
  "album" : {
    "album_type" : "album",
    "available_markets" : [ "AR", "AU", "AT", "BE", "BO", "BR", "BG", "CA", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "DO", "DE", "EC", "EE", "SV", "FI", "FR", "GR", "GT", "HN", "HK", "HU", "IS", "IE", "IT", "LV", "LT", "LU", "MY", "MT", "MX", "NL", "NZ", "NI", "NO", "PA", "PY", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "SG", "SK", "ES", "SE", "CH", "TW", "TR", "UY", "US", "GB", "AD", "LI", "MC", "ID" ],
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/6400dnyeDyD2mIFHfkwHXN"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6400dnyeDyD2mIFHfkwHXN",
    "id" : "6400dnyeDyD2mIFHfkwHXN",
    "images" : [ {
      "height" : 640,
      "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/e17011b2aa33289dfa6c0828a0e40d6b56ad8820",
      "width" : 640
    }, {
      "height" : 300,
      "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/fe11a648ea61a3c2422c21b3ff8a870a6efbc608",
      "width" : 300
    }, {
      "height" : 64,
      "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/4b04fa350781271b1af24d804c1badec1f8e63c7",
      "width" : 64
    } ],
    "name" : "Pablo Honey",
    "type" : "album",
    "uri" : "spotify:album:6400dnyeDyD2mIFHfkwHXN"
  },
  "artists" : [ {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb",
    "id" : "4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb",
    "name" : "Radiohead",
    "type" : "artist",
    "uri" : "spotify:artist:4Z8W4fKeB5YxbusRsdQVPb"
  } ],
  "available_markets" : [ "AR", "AU", "AT", "BE", "BO", "BR", "BG", "CA", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DK", "DO", "DE", "EC", "EE", "SV", "FI", "FR", "GR", "GT", "HN", "HK", "HU", "IS", "IE", "IT", "LV", "LT", "LU", "MY", "MT", "MX", "NL", "NZ", "NI", "NO", "PA", "PY", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "SG", "SK", "ES", "SE", "CH", "TW", "TR", "UY", "US", "GB", "AD", "LI", "MC", "ID" ],
  "disc_number" : 1,
  "duration_ms" : 238640,
  "explicit" : true,
  "external_ids" : {
    "isrc" : "GBAYE9200070"
  },
  "external_urls" : {
    "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/track/6b2oQwSGFkzsMtQruIWm2p"
  },
  "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6b2oQwSGFkzsMtQruIWm2p",
  "id" : "6b2oQwSGFkzsMtQruIWm2p",
  "name" : "Creep",
  "popularity" : 77,
  "preview_url" : "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/e7eb60e9466bc3a27299ea8803aadf4fa9cf795c",
  "track_number" : 2,
  "type" : "track",
  "uri" : "spotify:track:6b2oQwSGFkzsMtQruIWm2p"
}
```